# Insert string into string?

Tags: php

I have a number of images being uploaded to a site with random file names e.g.

```
http://www.mysite.com/uploads/images/apicture23.jpg
http://www.mysite.com/uploads/images/anotherpicture203.jpeg
http://www.mysite.com/uploads/images/another.picture203.png
http://www.mysite.com/uploads/images/athird-picture101.gif
```

Is it possible in PHP to somehow insert immediately before the file extension (`.jpg`, `.jpeg` `.png` or `.gif`) part of the url another string such as `-300x200` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$out = preg_replace('/\.[a-z]+$/i','-300x200\0',$in);
```

This basically does this, reading from left to right:

It replaces anything starting with a dot (`\.`), followed by one or more (`+`) characters in the range `a-z`, at the end (`$`) of the string, case-insensitive (`i`), by `-300x200` followed by the part of the string just matched (`\0`).

Comment: Please explain to the OP what this does and how it works, and link to documentation where appropriate.

Comment: I am positive that the top 1 hit in google on `preg_replace` will lead to the official php.net documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to rename your file name when you upload the image, the bellowing class will help you:

```
<?php

    function thumbnail( $img, $source, $dest, $maxw, $maxh ) {      
        $jpg = $source.$img;

        if( $jpg ) {
            list( $width, $height  ) = getimagesize( $jpg ); //$type will return the type of the image
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $jpg );

            if( $maxw >= $width && $maxh >= $height ) {
                $ratio = 1;
            }elseif( $width > $height ) {
                $ratio = $maxw / $width;
            }else {
                $ratio = $maxh / $height;
            }

            $thumb_width = round( $width * $ratio ); //get the smaller value from cal # floor()
            $thumb_height = round( $height * $ratio );

            $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );
            imagecopyresampled( $thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width, $height );

            $path = $dest.$img."-300x200.jpg";
            imagejpeg( $thumb, $path, 75 );
        }
        imagedestroy( $thumb );
        imagedestroy( $source );
    }

?>
```

Where

```
      $img         => image file name
      $source      => the path to the source image
      $dest        => the path to the destination image
      $maxw        => the maximum of the image width you desire
      $maxh        => the minimum one
```